# How to retain last 1000 ids (from 99001 to 100000) from a table and deleting rest of them?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 100000 rows. I want to retain only last 1% of the rows? How can I do that? Also ID should start from 1. I am using MS SQL 2012

Comment: mysql or sql server?

Comment: Is the ID field autonumeric?

Comment: Last in repsect to what? Do you have a date? Are the Ids numbered in ascending order where to highest are last?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will transfer last 10% of rows to a temporary table, truncate the original table and later transfer them back to the original table.

**Example:**

```
SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT [Required Columns] INTO #temp FROM Table1 ORDER BY ID DESC

TRUNCATE TABLE Table1

INSERT INTO Table1
SELECT [Required Columns excluding ID] FROM #temp ORDER BY ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete the lines you're no longer interested in

```
DELETE FROM <yourTable> WHERE ID < 99000
```

and then update the ID

```
UPDATE <yourTable> SET ID=ID-99000
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option...

```
WITH
    cte_AddRN AS (
        SELECT 
            td.ID,
            rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY td.id DESC)
        FROM
            #TestData td
        )
DELETE arn 
FROM
    cte_AddRN arn
WHERE 
    arn.rn > 1000;
```